# python3.6 ImportError: cannot import name 'reduce'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from functools import reduce
```

I'm using python 3.6.2, and this is the only code that shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\Pythons\oop.py", line 50, in <module>
from functools import reduce   
ImportError: cannot import name 'reduce'
Process returned 1 (0x1)   execution time : 0.145 s
```

I will find this problem because I made a mistake in another code,

```
from enum import Enum
```

It reported the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Pythons\oop.py", line 50, in <module>
from enum import Enum
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\enum.py", line 3, in <module>
from functools import reduce ImportError: cannot import name 'reduce'
```

So I just looked at the `enum. Py` source,Found in line 3

```
from functools import reduce
```

Ladies and gentlemen, in centos7.2 installed python3.6.2 is completely out of any problems, but under the Windows 10 professional version installed, will appear these problems above, seems I installed out of the question, however, many times I've uninstalled, installed the many times repeatedly, still won't do, don't know without those documents, who can tell me how to through the command line in the Windows environment to install it?

Comment: so python can't import `reduce` from `functools`. I can't find a class/method named reduce neither in python 3. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/functools.py - this was in python 2 available https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Comment: That code works fine on https://www.python.org/shell/ which uses version3.6.0. maybe reinstall, or do a full install with all python packages?

Comment: I just installed 3.6.2 and I'm not able to replicate. `reduce` is even listed on the [documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Comment: Sounds like you named a file something you shouldn't.

Comment: To clarify the comment from @user2357112, I've run into this error when I've created a file named `functools.py` in a location higher up on the path than the intended import. Rename the file you created called `functools.py`. If this is not the case, then your installation is likely bad.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.6 should have reduce in functools. To debug your problem, try this:

```
import functools
for obj in dir(functools):
    print(obj)
```

I would expect an output similar to (tried it here: https://www.python.org/shell/):

```
MappingProxyType
RLock
WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS
WRAPPER_UPDATES
WeakKeyDictionary
_CacheInfo
_HashedSeq
__all__
__builtins__
__cached__
__doc__
__file__
__loader__
recursive_repr
__name__
__package__
__spec__
_c3_merge
_c3_mro
_compose_mro
_convert
_find_impl
_ge_from_gt
_ge_from_le
_ge_from_lt
_gt_from_ge
_gt_from_le
_gt_from_lt
_le_from_ge
_le_from_gt
_le_from_lt
_lru_cache_wrapper
_lt_from_ge
_lt_from_gt
_lt_from_le
_make_key
cmp_to_key
get_cache_token
lru_cache
namedtuple
partial
partialmethod
recursive_repr
reduce
singledispatch
total_ordering
update_wrapper
wraps
```

My guess is more than reduce will be missing. In any case, it looks like an Uninstall than Reinstall is in order. You may have accidently edited the file or corrupted it in some way. Sometimes an IDE could take you to that function and it would be easy to edit it accidentally.

Comment: __builtins__
__cached__
__doc__
__file__
__loader__
__name__
__package__
__spec__
functools   I just showed that

Answer (score 0):

Don't take care of those errors. Just try to use **functools** in your code :

```
import functools 

# Create a list of strings: stark
stark = ['robb', 'sansa', 'arya', 'eddard', 'jon']

# Use reduce() to apply a lambda function over stark: result
result = functools.reduce((lambda item1,item2:item1 + item2), stark)
```

or like that :

```
# Import reduce from functools
from functools import reduce

# Create a list of strings: stark
stark = ['robb', 'sansa', 'arya', 'eddard', 'jon']

# Use reduce() to apply a lambda function over stark: result
result = reduce((lambda item1,item2:item1 + item2), stark)
```